# Is it possible to have a code which cannot be solved by computer

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness

I was looking at Turing machines and Turing completeness and I was wondering whether it is possible to prove that there is a problem which cannot be solved by a Turing complete computer or whether it is possible to prove the opposite.

Comment: What do you mean by "a code which cannot be solved"? What is "code"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I meant problem

Comment: You may take a look at [undecidable problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem).